# I cant break a loop

Tags: ruby, loops

My program cannot exit the loop, if **@response == "201"** should break the loop.

```
class Hello
    def initialize(a, b)
        @a = a
        @b = b
    end

    def something()
        @response = "201"

    end
end

loop do
    puts "write something"
    a = gets.chomp
    puts "write something again"
    b = gets.chomp

    hello = Hello.new(a,b)
    hello.something()

    break if @response == "201"
end
```

This code is an example reduced on another.

Comment: Your loop doesn't know what @response is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `@response` is an instance variable so it's encapsulated inside your class `Hello` and not available outside of it. One of the possible (but not the only one) solutions to make your code work could be as follows

```
class Hello

    # Make @response available in the interface
    attr_reader :response

    def initialize(a, b)
        @a = a
        @b = b
    end

    def something()
        @response = "201"

    end
end

loop do
    puts "write something"
    a = gets.chomp
    puts "write something again"
    b = gets.chomp

    hello = Hello.new(a,b)
    hello.something()

    # using class property to stop the loop
    break if hello.response == "201"
end
```

Comment: Thank U very much

Comment: It might be more accurate to say that @response is encapsulated within an instance of `Hello`.